# Hosting a Private maven repository on GitHub

Tags: git, maven, github

I know there is a way to host your maven repos on github by making it public. but is there a way to host a private repo on github? the examples I have found on the web like: https://engineering.groupon.com/2014/misc/maven-and-github-forking-a-github-repository-and-hosting-its-maven-artifacts/ are all public repos. My maven repo is a private repo and i want to host it as a private repo

Comment: instead of using github. You may consider to use a private maven repo as a service solution in the cloud. https://repsy.io is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you [upgrade](https://github.com/pricing) from **Free** to **Micro** on GitHub then you can have private repositories.

You also need to make sure that you authenticate properly when accessing the repositories even for reading otherwise it will appear as the private repositories do not exist.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have a proper github account and the repo is private. but for some reason the maven repo can't be hosted if private. but works perfectly if i set to public

Comment: Is authentication is set up properly? If the repo is private you have to make sure that whatever process (maven in your case) is trying to access the repo is using the correct credentials

Comment: Yes I am using the right credentials, have also added to the .m2/setttings.xml of maven. but keep getting the following error = Could not find artifact za.co:projecx:jar:1.0 in projectx-mvn-repo